# Value not passing from AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

In the View File

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function fetch_comp(val){

        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"<?php echo base_url()?>admin/admin_main/fetchData",
          data:{'c_name':val},
          datatype: "JSON",
          success: function(data){
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#job_description").val(obj.job_description);
            $("#ctc").val(obj.ctc);
            $("#location").val(obj.location);
          }
        })
      }
</script>
```

In the Controller File

```
public function fetchData(){
    $val = $this->input->post('c_name');
    echo "<script>alert('$val');</script>";
}
```

The value is not being passed from the view page to controller page.

Comment: You echo a string. How on earth do you get properties of it?

Comment: You're sure that val is being passed correctly into your fetch_comp function?  console.log(val) before the ajax to verify.

Comment: @RyanTuosto. Yes I am getting val correctly.

Comment: echo seems like a weird way to pass data from the controller to the view.  Are you using a framework or is this something you've custom built?

Comment: Yes I'm using codeignitor framework.  Then what should be instead of echo?

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view